# Export to csv/excel way to include leading zero

Tags: mysql

Exporting select query data from mysql to csv & opening with excel, the leading zeros are gone.

Although the column is varchar, when the data gets exported, it writes like

`4567 instead of 04567,` is there a way to preserve the leading zero while exporting to csv?

Comment: I export after i run the select query in sql yog, once i get the output, i use the option from sql yog to export to .csv.

Comment: a bare leading zero could lead to trouble. Many systems will see 04567 as an octal number and treat it as such, giving you 2423 decimal

Comment: That's for zip code & we need 0 in the export. FYI the DB has varchar for zip code, the output shown is correct, only export terminates that leading zero!

Comment: Correct answer is found at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/308352/207603, bottom line: put a equal "=" before the cell quotes, Example: "cell1",="04567","cell3"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to wrap the number in double quotes like: `...,"04567",...`, but then it will be interpreted as text in the spreadsheet so integer arithmetic will not work on it unless you do a conversion first (integers cannot begin with 0 in excel).

Comment: I run using select query, am not doing manually.

Comment: @Sharpeye, that makes no difference... Just wrap the double quotes around the output of your varchar column.

Comment: select zip_code from table1; -> do i wrap in the query? or in the excel, pls. brief a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Sharpeye SELECT CONCAT('"', zip_code, '"') FROM table1 will do it right in the query for you.

Comment: For those who have upvoted, and accepted as an answer, what version of MS Excel are you using? I am exporting a CSV file with PHP 5.3 and using MS Excel 2010 and wrapping a string with double-quotes such as this `"0078"` has **no** effect on how Excel displays it. It still chooses to cast it to an integer and strip the leading zeros. I've played around with a few different 3rd party extensions, but none of them seem to be able to resolve this problem.

Comment: @crmpicco Are you sure you are wrapping the string in double quotes? In PHP that would look like: `"\"0078\""` or `'"0078"'`

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I have found, however, that the SimpleExcel PHP extension works well and handles the stripping of leading zeros. It is available on GitHub and the support for it is good also - http://faisalman.github.com/simple-excel-php/

Comment: At least with MSExcel 2013 zeros are being stripped

Comment: Doesn't work with Excel. Both Excel and Numbers (for Mac) will still convert it to numbers. You'd have to use the "Data -> Get External Data -> Import Text from file" functionality in Excel to get it displayed as text. The only way to force excel to display numbers as text from the input, without the user having to do anything, is by outputting an excel file and specifying a "custom number format" in it.

Comment: And with whatever version of Excel comes with "Microsoft 365" (April 2020).

Answer (score 3):

Your CSV file will have the leading zeroes. Just open it in a text editor and see.

The problem is that importing into Excel and Numbers (for Mac) will remove leading zeroes, and convert strings with numbers into number format. This is by intent, since a lot of input into excel comes from various sources, where numbers often are treated as text. And when you put numbers into excel you typically want to do something with them as numbers (ie. calculations) and not as text. So they have made it automatically handle the most common use case.

The only way to force excel to display numbers as text from the input, without the user having to do anything, is by outputting an excel file and specifying a "custom number format" in it. I recommend using a XLS export library for this, as it doesn't seem as simple as adding a line of config text into a CSV file.

Comment: This is correct.  The leading zeros are in the text file and can been seen if, for example, you open the .csv file with Notepad.  The problem arises when you open the csv with Excel.  It treats zip codes as numbers and strips off the leading zeros.  

A way around this is to open Excel first, then do a File - Open on the csv file.  This gives you an import wizard allowing you to define delimiters etc.  In the wizard, format the zip code column as Text.  This will preserve the leading 0.

Answer (score 1):

Place the data in between single quotes when you export the csv.

i.e. 04567 will be '04567'

Comment: SELECT CONCAT('\'', zip_code , '\'') from table1

Comment: This is also helpful, thanks leoh.

Comment: Now Excel is displaying these quotation marks which is an unwanted effect. Also I will need to remove them while processing to file to get the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSRS, go the the textbox you need to have leading zeros, and over in the text box pane, scroll down to format and enter zeroes for as many numbers will be in the number. For example, in a zip code, you would enter 00000 into the format box. I know this works for Excel 2013.