# Excel file converts numerous zeros into a single one

Tags: java, excel, csv

Hey guys I am creating a CSV file and there is mandatory zeros that need to be added, When review CSV it does have them but once i try to open it with Excel it converts them into a single one, what can i do here?

I am not using any Excel library and would like to avoid it somehow, I am just using using a PrintWriter to generate csv extension file and write string values into it.

[Csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgKc4.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEwnH.png)

```
 public String asString() {
    String CSV_SEPARATOR = ";";
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(CSV_SEPARATOR);
    stringJoiner.add("PT")
            .add(range)
            .add("50")
            .add(personNumber)
            .add("30")
            .add("000")
            .add("000000")
            .add(localDate.toString())
            .add("2")
            .add(" ")
            .add("00")
            .add("HRYOU")
            .add("39")
            .add(onlineSystem);
    return stringJoiner.toString();
}
```

Comment: Might be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7070788/1004631

Comment: Can you please paste the csv and excel results as code formatted text also, so user that cannot see the images, can see what you mean?