# Export to CSV from Gridview when data contains commas

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I am trying to export to CSV, however the problem I am facing is when the data contained within the grid view contains comma's.   Since the a ",", is used as the delimiter this is causing all sorts of issues within the csv.  Below is the code.  Any ideas how I can avoid this?

```
  try
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(CsvFpath, false);

            string columnHeaderText = "";

            int countColumn = dataGridViewLogging.ColumnCount - 1;

            if (countColumn >= 0)
            {
                columnHeaderText = dataGridViewLogging.Columns[0].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
            {
                columnHeaderText = columnHeaderText + ',' + dataGridViewLogging.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }


            csvFileWriter.WriteLine(columnHeaderText);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRowObject in dataGridViewLogging.Rows)
            {
                if (!dataRowObject.IsNewRow)
                {
                    string dataFromGrid = "";

                    dataFromGrid = dataRowObject.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= countColumn; i++)
                    {
                        dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString();

                        csvFileWriter.WriteLine(dataFromGrid);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Change the delimiter to `;` and set `sep=;` first in the csv-file could work.

Comment: Wrap the fields in double quotes which can contain commas and use an [available csv parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) instead of doing it manually.

Comment: can you not simply use a different less common character as a delimiter such as a `|`, either that or wrap the offending text in `""` this should then be parseable by most applications.

Comment: Wouldn't encapsulating your dataitem in double quotes solve your problem? i.e. "data item 1","data item 2","data item, 3" etc.

Comment: What is the targeted consumer of this CSV file?

Comment: @Mario your suggestion works, but then what if the OP has a ; in his data? or anyother chosen separator?

Comment: @Les To answer your questions directly; it wouldn't work. But, this just a simple solution to the OP's problem, as long as he uses a delimiter that's not used (that's way I just made a comment and not an answer). Usually it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an escape character, and use a parser that understands how to deal with escapes.  You can quickly write an Escape() extension and an Unescape() extension....

```
public static class ExtentionClass
{
    public static string Escape(this string str)
    {
          return str.Replace("\\","\\\\").Replace(",","\\,");
    }
    public static string Unescape(this string str)
    {
          return str.Replace("\\\\","\\").Replace("\\,",",");
    }
}
```

now you can change your line to...

```
dataFromGrid = dataFromGrid + ',' + dataRowObject.Cells[i].Value.ToString().Escape();
```

But, you are probably wanting to view the output in Excel, then \ doesn't work...  It needs to be double quoted.

```
...
    public static string Escape(this string str)
    {
        return "\"" + str.Replace("\"","\"\"") + "\"";
    }
```

You can read more at...
[CSV for Excel, Including Both Leading Zeros and Commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308324/csv-for-excel-including-both-leading-zeros-and-commas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any library for export into CSV.