# preventing MS Excel from stripping leading zeros with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have the following sample line in a CSV file I am generating with PHP. When I `cat` the file this is what I see:

```
541787,271561,"04/01/2013 09:26:35",18801872,Many,"PINSTRIPE JACKET",18806821872,75.00,GBP,1,0078,5051916991872
```

However, when I open this file in MS Excel the "0078" has been changed to "78" - so MS Excel has taken it upon itself to strip the leading zeros. It has also converted the EAN13 number (in Column L) to an exponent.

[image: Stripped Zeros]

In terms of the PHP code I am outputting the file to the browser with the following code, which works in principal, but I would like to know if there is a way to control the stripping of the leading zeros with PHP?

```
// set the headers
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=_report_' . date('Y-m-d-His') . '.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

echo $report->getCSVOutput();
exit;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSV for Excel, Including Both Leading Zeros and Commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308324/csv-for-excel-including-both-leading-zeros-and-commas)

Comment: ^ if you search through the related column on the right you might spot valuable resources that just answer your question (which none of the answers here actually did taking aside the workaround to use XML instead of CSV which technically might not qualify).

Comment: I found a raw CSV solution while fiddling around. I answered on [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39577123/1967768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that with a small tweak (as suggested by the owner) to [SimpleExcel](http://faisalman.github.com/simple-excel-php/) this package *can* handle the stripping of leading zeros.

I am using the code below:

```
/**
 * get the order data in Microsoft Excel XML format (to be used when output to the browser directly)
 * @return void
 */
public function getExcelXMLOutput() {

    // instantiate new object (will automatically construct the parser & writer type as XML)
    $excel = new SimpleExcel('xml');                    

    // add some data to the writer
    $excel->writer->setData($this->orders);                                                 

    // save the file with specified name
    // and specified target (default to browser)           
    $excel->writer->saveFile('report_' . date('Y-m-d-His'));

}
```

The code amendment required me to change the `XMLWriter` class in the `addRow` method to:

```
$datatype = is_string($val) ? 'String' : (is_numeric($val) ? 'Number' : 'String');
```

Answer (score 1):

With the CSV format, there is nothing you can do about it. Since it doesn't contain any formatting, Excel analyzes each values and tries to guess what it most likely is.

So *0078* becomes *78* (since Excel thinks it's a number) and *5051916991872* becomes *5.05192E+12* since that's the default way of representing long numbers.

If this is a serious problem, you need to use a file format where you can specify the type of the values. The easiest one is probably *XML Spreadsheet 2003*. You can create a template by formatting an Excel spreadsheet the way you want it, then save it as *XML Spreadsheet 2003* and open it in a text editor.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from PHP though? I've had a play around with a number of extensions such as SimpleExcel and PHPExcel, but they don't let you specify (when exporting) the data type of a value? PHPExcel lets you specify the data type at _cell level_, but that's not ideal when you don't know the cell name when exporting. I just want to be able to say that `0078` is a string and not an integer to be converted by Excel automatically. Using a third-party extension is not a problem, but those mentioned don't seem to provide this functionality unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A column value that starts with a single quote `'` will be treated as Text by Excel and preserves the leading zeros.

Comment: Try it: it does not work the way you expect. The `'` will be visible when it's read from the CSV file. You'll have to select the cell and hit return to make it disappear.

Comment: Yes, although the `'` preserves the `00` it does remain when you view the CSV file in Excel. So I'm no further forward in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

When using dates the following seems to work.

Simply pad the the date with whitespace likeso:

```
$csvVal = '" ' . $DateTime->format('m/d/y') . ' "';
```